# Not able to send form parameters to the server

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring-mvc

We are getting a issue wherein while submitting a form via javascript one of the parameters (`invoiceCodes`) is not sent to the server. Below is the snippet of the javascript code.

The flow is as follows. When user clicks on "Print" button `validateTransition()` method is called in which we make a ajax call. After response of that ajax we call `couponPopup(url, invoiceCodes)`. In this function we submit `newWinForm` but sometimes `invoiceCodes` parameter is sent empty.

Also `checkForInvoiceCode` is true in this case which require user to input invoice codes

Is there anything wrong in the manner in which we are putting values in the form which may lead to `invoiceCodes` being not sent sometimes.

```
function couponPopup(url, invoiceCodes)
{
    var selectedOrders = '';
    $(".selectedOrder:checked").each(function() {
        selectedOrders += $(this).val() + ',';
    });

    var frm = document.forms["newWinForm"];
    frm.action = url;
    frm.selectedShipments.value= selectedOrders; 
    frm.invoiceCodes.value = invoiceCodes; 
    console.log("Selected orders are "+selectedOrders);
    console.log("Invoice codes with them in order are "+invoiceCodes);
    document.getElementById("hiddenInvoiceCodes").value=invoiceCodes;
    document.getElementById("hiddenselectedShipments").value=selectedOrders;
    frm.submit();
    return false;
}

function validateTransition() {
    $('#statusChangeSuccess').hide();
    $('#statusChangeFail').hide();

    var selectedOrders = '';
    var invoiceCodes = '';
    var flag = 0;
    var spaceError = 0;
    var commaError = 0;

    $(".selectedOrder:checked").each(function() {
        selectedOrders += $(this).val() + ',';
        <c:if test="${checkForInvoiceCode}">
        var emptyPattern = /^\s*$/;
        var commaPattern = /,/;
        var inv_code = $("#invoice-code-" + $(this).val()).val().trim();
        if (emptyPattern.test(inv_code)) {
            spaceError = 1;
            flag = 1;

        }
        if (commaPattern.test(inv_code)) {
            commaError = 1;
            flag = 1;

        }
        invoiceCodes += inv_code + ",";
        </c:if>
    });

    if(selectedOrders=='') {
        alert('Please select at least one order');
        return false;
    }

    if ( flag ) {
        if ( commaError ) {
            alert('One or more specified codes have comma, please remove comma from them');
        }
        if ( spaceError ) {
            alert('One or more specified codes has been left blank, please fill them up');
        }
        if ( !commaError && !spaceError ) {
            alert('Please contact tech');
        }

        return false;
    }

    var inputdata = {"selectedShipments" : selectedOrders,
        "statusCode" : "PRINT"
    };

    //this is where we are making an ajax call 
    jQuery(function($){
            setTimeout(function(){                      
                var ajaxUrl = '/product/update/';

                $.ajax({url:ajaxUrl, type: "POST", dataType: 'json', data:inputdata , success: function(data) {
                    if(data['status'] == 'success') {
                        //couponPopup function is called where form is submitted
                        couponPopup("${path.http}/product/print/", invoiceCodes);
                        $('#statusChangeSuccess').html(data['message']).show();

                        $(".selectedOrder:checked").each(function() {
                            $("#row-" + $(this).val()).remove();
                        });

                    } else{
                        $('#statusChangeFail').html(data['message']).show();
                    }
                }});
        }, 10 );
    });

    return false;
}

<form id="newWinForm" name="newWinForm" action="" method="post" target="_blank" >
    <input type="hidden" id="hiddenselectedShipments" name="selectedShipments" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" id="hiddenInvoiceCodes" name="invoiceCodes" value="" />
</form>
```

Controller for the form. Invoice codes is sometimes empty even when we are sending it from client side.

```
@RequestMapping("/product/print")
public void printSelectedPendingOrders(@RequestParam("selectedShipments") String selectedShipments,
        @RequestParam(defaultValue = "", value = "invoiceCodes", required = false) String invoiceCodes, ModelMap modelMap, HttpServletResponse httpResponse)
        throws IOException, DocumentException, ParserConfigurationException, SAXException {
```

Comment: being not sent sometimes, Are you getting values sometimes

Comment: It's possible the way you use trim function is causing an error preventing to post correctly value. Please read documentation http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/ Usage is $.trim(str) and not .trim() on a string field

Comment: Don't know if its related to your problem or not but your mixing jQuery and regular javascript. use one or the other to avoid a maintenance nightmare

Comment: why do you have settimeout wrapping your ajax?

Comment: @franchez if it was the problem then alert must have been there since then inv_code will be empty

Comment: @shadow yes they are sent sometimes... I am getting this error in my production environment but could not replicate the same in testing environment

Comment: @carter yes it should not be there.

Comment: I would not chain regular js funcs like trim(). Also, put your js through a linter.  Is difficult to know if you're getting auto injected semicolons in unexpected places.  But seriously if this happens on prod and not test, then you need to look at the differences between the two not look for a problem that doesn't exist on test.